# Typescript + jasmine.createSpy()

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm writing unit tests for my angular project with Typescript

When I try to create mock for some service, I use this way:

```
const serviceMock = <IMyService>{
    method: _.noop,
};

beforeEach(inject($injector => {
   testingService = new AccountingService(serviceMock);

   spyOn(serviceMock, 'method').and.callFake(()=>'hello');
 }
```

this works ok
but when I try to use `jasmine.createSpy()`, I get compilation errors:

```
const serviceMock = <IMyService>{
    method: jasmine.createSpy('method').and.callFake(()=>'hello'),
};

Type '{ method: Spy;}' cannot be converted to type 'MyService'. Property 'getParams' is missing in type '{ method: Spy;}'.
```

But `getParams` is private method of `MyService`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 26):

Use the type already defined and used by Jasmine `SpyObj<T>`.

```js
const serviceMock: jasmine.SpyObj<IMyService> = jasmine.createSpyObj<IMyService>('service',['method']);
```

This way every method of IMyService will be augmented with the Spy ones:

```
serviceMock.method.and.callFake(()=>'hello');
```

Comment: I'm up-voting for the good use of service type. One should use `jasmine.SpyObj<IMyService>`  as type instead of `IMyService`

Answer (score 4):

Try it with a mapped type

```
export type Spied<T> = {  
  [Method in keyof T]: jasmine.Spy;
};
```

and cast your service mock with it

```
const serviceMock = Spied<IMyService>{
```

Take a look [here](http://pragmatic-coder.net/typesafe-jasmine-spies/) for a detailed description

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Partial type:

```
const serviceMock = <Partial<IMyService>>{
```

For more information check out: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

Comment: it hadn't helped, but thank you for Partial type, it was new for me